# Running APE Server in a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, ape

I have been trying to set-up an Ajax Push Engine (APE) Server in a virtual machine, and have run into a bit of a snag. The problem is that the APE server cannot be accessed outside of the virtual machine.

**Setup:**

- Guest OS: Ubuntu 10.10 (I believe) with the ape package installed

  - IP Address: 192.168.56.1 using a host-only network adapter
  - APE Server running on port 6969

If I try `wget 127.0.0.1:6969` in the virtual machine, I get a response.

If I try `wget 192.168.56.1:6969` from the host OS, I get a `Connection Refused` message.

If I ping `192.168.56.1`, I also get a response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up redoing everything from scratch, and it worked, so I must have got it right somehow. For the benefit of others...

To get APE Server running in a virtual machine (in particular, using VirtualBox), you need to do the following:

### Setting up the environment

- Download and install VirtualBox
- Open VirtualBox, and go to `File > Preferences`, then `Network`

  - Confirm that there exists a host-only network `vboxnet0` (if not, create it). Take note of its IPv4 address (`192.168.56.1`, in my case)
- Create a new Ubuntu Virtual Machine
- Start the Virtual Machine

### Getting the Libraries

- Add the PPA for `libmysqlclient15off`, a pre-requisite for APE Server:

  ```
  username# gpg --keyserver  hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
  username# gpg -a --export CD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.percona.com/apt maverick main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona.list'
  ```
- Install `libmysqlclient15off`

  ```
  sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15off
  ```
- Get and install the [latest version of APE server](http://www.ape-project.org/stable/APE_Server-1.1.1-amd64.deb)
- Edit /etc/network/interfaces, and add the following to the end:

  ```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.56.101
      netmask 255.255.255.0
  ```
- Close the virtual machine and go into its settings. Change the network settings for the first interface to `Host-only Adapter`

### Setting Up APE

- Restart the Virtual Machine, and ensure that the APE daemon is running

  ```
  username# ps -ef | grep "aped"
  ```
- If you need to, make changes to `/etc/ape/ape.conf`

### Final Steps

- Add the following to your hosts file, or some variation:

  ```
  192.168.56.101            local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            0.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            1.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            2.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            3.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            4.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            5.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            6.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            7.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            8.local.site.com
  192.168.56.101            9.local.site.com
  ```
- Access your new APE server via `local.site.com:6969`

Answer (score 0):

Check APE config file. Are you binding to the right IP ? By default it's 127.0.0.1